# In a .NET app, Is there anyway to monitor what the UI thread is spending it's time doing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am having an issue where a WPF application wrapped in a panel is having problems properly rendering its child controls...resulting in sort of flashing, where the child controls are constantly toggling between two sizes as wpf struggles to render it.
Is anyone aware of away to monitor the UI thread and possibly drill down into it to see where it is spending its time?
I have tried ProcMon but it does not provide much info.  Additionally a few profiling tools such as RedAnts provide useful data as far as our code goes, but because in my case, it seems our performance issue is with Wpf trying do render some ui components, it is not helpful.

Any other tools that can target specifically the UI thread and provide information regarding what it is doing?

Comment: what are you doing to the UI? WPF does not do that on it's own. Post the relevant parts of the code and XAML. Also, you can try Perforator or something.

Comment: Question is off topic voting to close. But If you're using visual studio it have a performance profiler make use of it for free of cost.

Comment: Sounds like you may have some rounding issues or event loops where it is going back and forth repeatedly. I know this may sound dumb, but have you tried simply Debug->Break and checking the UI thread's call stack a few times? I've done that before to see where it was in the code when it was bogged down with something.. but I hadn't tried it in WPF which quite a bit more complicated than WinForms

Comment: Have you tried the [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx) in the Windows SDK?

Comment: @sriram: how is this off topic?  as mentioned, i have used a few profiler.  net profiler is unusable in our case (large app)..it takes well over 10 min to process data after running only 2 min.  Ant profiler is better, but doesn't provide details of .net core library code.

Comment: This is a question of incorrect implementation control sizing and allocation on a parent. Just need to read WPF Controls documentation

Comment: @mike, i have used the the Performace Wizard in VS to no avail.  it just hangs trying to parse the data i think.  Is the performance suite diff?  i will have a look

Comment: **Any other tools that can target specifically the UI thread and provide information regarding what it is doing?** This is what I mean by off topic. `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. `

Comment: @arthur - it is and it isn't.  the problem is it is not consistent. So i'm trying to undestand better what's going on...hence the true point of this post - how to drill down into the ui thread and see what its spending its time on.

Comment: @mike01010 ok, anyway, CUSTOM controls DO not JUMP, if implemented correctly. BUT even WPF base controls get visually visible JUMPS, if got incorrect XAML for a container form or get declarative properties on a form preventing WPF to use hardware acceleration or incorrect options (so lags are so great that controls can't be fast enougth to properly resize itself in time due to the rasterization effects)

Comment: can't stop laughing at the 'closed as off-topic' drama :)